# How can I tell if an instance variable using an interface has a custom attribute applied?

Tags: c#, custom-attributes

I want to be able to check for the presence of a custom attribute on an instance of a class, but I want to be able to perform that check from within that class's constructor. Take a look at this pseudo-code:

```
namespace TestPackage
{
    public class MyAttribute : Attribute { }
    public interface IMyThing { }

    public class MyThing : IMyThing
    {
        private bool HasMyAttribute { get; set; }

        public MyThing()
        {
            if (/* some check for custom attribute */)
            {
                HasMyAttribute = true;
            }
        }
    }

    public class MyWrapper
    {
        [MyAttribute]
        private readonly IMyThing _myThing;

        public MyWrapper()
        {
            _myThing = new MyThing();
        }
    }
}
```

The if-statement where I have the code comment is what I'd like to fill in. Is this possible?

Comment: No, that isn't possible.  The attribute isn't applied to the class instance, it's applied to the field.

Comment: This seems like an anti-pattern to me...

Comment: Attributes are defined statically in the code and are therefore static, they are not bound to instances. They are applied to a type or to members of this type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attributes are defined statically in the code and are therefore static, they are not bound to instances. They are applied to a type or to members of this type.

In your case you could have your wrapper implement `IMyThing` and use it instead of the original type and then apply the attribute to the class.

```
[MyAttribute]
public class MyWrapper : IMyThing
{
    private readonly IMyThing _myThing;

    public MyWrapper()
    {
        _myThing = new MyThing();
    }

    public void DoMyThingStuff()
    {
        _myThing.DoMyThingStuff();
    }
}
```

And then you can check for the attribute like this:

```
bool CheckAttribute(IMyThing myThing)
{
    Type t = myThing.GetType();
    return t.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyAttribute), false).Length > 0;
}
```

If an object of the original class is passed, you get `false`. If a wrapper object is passed you get `true`.

You could also derive a class from the original class instead of creating a wrapper.

```
[MyAttribute]
public class MyDerived : MyThing
{
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use this constructor:

```
public MyThing
{
                HasMyAttribute =false;
                foreach (MemberInfo item in this.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(false))
                {
                        if(item.Name=="MyAttribute")
                            HasMyAttribute =true;
                }

}
```

Comment: The answer that is been marked as answer is almost the same approach